# Problem with revolut api transactions list

Tags: python-3.x, open-banking

are few days that we are experiencing trouble with revolut api.
We use that library: https://github.com/useme-com/revolut-python
Now when we try to retrive a list of transactions we receive:

```
root@# python3 transactions.py
HTTP 400 for https://b2b.revolut.com/api/1.0/transactions: Duplicate key User@XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX (attempted merging values XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX and YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYY)
```

The code is pretty straightforward, to debug basically:

```
[...]
# Enable Session
  session = RenewableSession(refreshtoken,clientid,jwttoken)

# Create API Client
  revolut = Client(session)

# Transactions Display
  for transaction in revolut.transactions():
     print(transaction)
[...]
```

The same code, from our side, worked until 3 days ago, without errors.
Any ideas on what's going on?
Possible that exist a failure from revolut side?
They are not responding on this (already opened a ticket about).
ty

Comment: I am having the same issue and would like to know

Comment: this time was a revolut problem. it was resolved by them in 3 days circa

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue while using a high `count` param

https://b2b.revolut.com/api/1.0/transactions?count=1000

Reducing count to 100 or 200 made me get a good response. I think Revolut has some issues when sending API response that includes a very old historical transaction due to changes in data structure/merging etc at their end

Comment: thanks but this time was a revolut problem. it was resolved by them in 3 days circa